# Code 141 (error: success/error was not called) on Parse Cloud Code nested queries

Tags: ios, parse-platform

**Background:**

I have a Parse database of images. Simply, my code does this:

A user, through a Parse Cloud call requests an image ("getNewPicture"). Nested within I check if he has seen any pictures before (alongside other requirements) and if so deliver one specific picture (getSpecifiedPicture). If he has not, then I deliver a new picture (getNewPicture).

**Issue:**

Calling "getNewPicture" through Parse Cloud Code function I get an error code 141. What's strange is that it works through Android but not iOS.

**My code:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getNewPicture", function(request, response) {
  var SeenPictures = Parse.Object.extend("SeenPictures");
  var query = new Parse.Query(SeenPictures);
  var username = request.params.username;
  var notWantedPics = [];
  query.ascending("createdAt");
  query.equalTo("username", username);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i].get("likes") == 1 || results[i].get("dislikes") == 1) {
          notWantedPics.push(results[i].get("pictureId"));
          results.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
      if (results != 0) {
        getSpecifiedPicture(results[0].get("pictureId"), {
          success: function(returnValue) {
            response.success(returnValue);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
          }
        });
      } else {
        getNewPicture(username, notWantedPics, {
          success: function(returnValue) {
            response.success(returnValue);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
          }
        });  
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});

function getSpecifiedPicture(specifiedPic, callback) {
  var Pictures = Parse.Object.extend("Pictures");
  var pictures = new Parse.Query(Pictures);
  pictures.get(specifiedPic, {
    success: function(picture) {
      callback.success(picture);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      callback.error(error);
    }
  });
}

function getNewPicture(username, notWantedPics, callback) {
  var Pictures = Parse.Object.extend("Pictures");
  var pictures = new Parse.Query(Pictures);
  pictures.notEqualTo("photographerUserName", username);
  pictures.notContainedIn("objectId", notWantedPics);
  pictures.ascending("createdAt");
  pictures.find({
    success: function(results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        var object = results[0];
        //Some other fancy stuff
        object.save();
        callback.success(object);
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      callback.error(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Why am I getting code 141? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callbacks are a mess. I rewrote it to follow more of a promise chain style. Much easier to follow. Also, underscore.js is your friend. Hopefully I got your idea right.

```
var _ = require('underscore'); // Javascript Library

Parse.Cloud.define("getNewPicture", function(request, response) {

    var username = request.params.username;
    var notWantedPics = [];

    if (!username) {
        return response.error('No username.');
    }

    var query1 = new Parse.Query("SeenPictures");
    query1.ascending("createdAt");
    query1.equalTo("username", username);
    var SeenPictures = query1.find();

    return Parse.Promise.when([SeenPictures]).then(function (SeenPictures) {

        SeenPictures = _.filter(SeenPictures, function (SeenPicture) {
            if (SeenPicture.get("likes") == 1 || SeenPicture.get("dislikes") == 1) {
                notWantedPics.push(SeenPicture.get("pictureId"));
                return false;
            } 
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });

        // notWantedPics?

        if (SeenPictures > 0) {
            var query2 = new Parse.Query("Pictures");
            var Pictures = [query2.get(SeenPictures[0].get('pictureId'))];
        } 
        else {
            var query2 = new Parse.Query("Pictures");
            query2.notEqualTo("photographerUserName", username);
            query2.notContainedIn("objectId", notWantedPics);
            query2.ascending("createdAt");
            var Pictures = query2.find();
        }

        return Parse.Promise.when([Pictures]);

    }).then(function (Pictures) {

        if (Pictures > 0) {

            // Success
            return response.success(Pictures[0]);

        } else {
            return Parse.Promise.error("No pictures.");
        }

    }, function (error) {
        // Error
        return response.error(error);
    });

});
```

Comment: No problem! BTW, hi from Ottawa!